# How can I get the data by CUrl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I wanna get the data in the link:http://210.38.207.15:169/web/search.aspx

I use Curl in php.But when I access the link,show the message "HTTP/1.1 302 Found".

I guess that I had not add the cookie(ASP.NET_SessionId) into the CUrl.If I write

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIE,"ASP.NET_SessionId=05siup45vprgvvarkv4tsu55");
```

I can get the data what I want.

So,can you tell me How can I get the "ASP.NET_SessionId",I can't get it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had found the answer.
Because need the header,although I can't understand about it.Let me show the code flow.

```
 $url = "http://210.38.207.15:169/web/searchresult.aspx?anywords=android&dt=ALL&cl=ALL&dp=20&sf=M_PUB_YEAR&ob=DESC&sm=table&dept=ALL";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//the next line is important
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,zh-TW;q=0.4'));
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
print_r($data);
```